Spring boot graceful shutdown not waiting for loop to finish
I've implemented graceful shutdown for my app and I'm doing a test to ensure it's working as expected. The last message that should appear on the console should be "Done!". However this is not the case.
@Service
public class MyClass {
    private boolean keepRunning = true;

    @Async
    public void myMethod(){

        do {
            try {
                System.out.println("Start");
                Thread.sleep(10000);
                System.out.println("Done!");
            }catch (Exception e){
                logger.error(e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        } while(keepRunning);
    }


    @PreDestroy
    void stop() {
        System.out.println("Shutdown called!");
        this.keepRunning = false;
    }
}

I have also added server.shutdown=graceful to my application.properties file
This is the full output of the console when ending the app
Start
2024-11-09T12:58:52.932-05:00  INFO 7374 --- [myapp] [ionShutdownHook] o.s.b.w.e.tomcat.GracefulShutdown        : Commencing graceful shutdown. Waiting for active requests to complete
2024-11-09T12:58:52.935-05:00  INFO 7374 --- [myapp] [tomcat-shutdown] o.s.b.w.e.tomcat.GracefulShutdown        : Graceful shutdown complete
Shutdown called!

Process finished with exit code 1

Isn't the process supposed to wait for the loop to finish? If not is there anyway I can wait for the loop to finish before closing the app?
EDIT:
After implementing a custom taskExecutor like the one below
@Bean(name = "test")
public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(1);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(1);
    executor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
    executor.setThreadNamePrefix("test-");
    executor.initialize();
    return executor;
}

I also gave it the name prefix of "test-" to ensure the method is using it. I also made changes to the method
@Async("test")
public void myMethod(){
    do {
        try {
            System.out.println("Start " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            System.out.println("Done!");
        }catch (Exception e){
            logger.error(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    } while(keepRunning);
}

The app still ends before printing the message "Done!"
Start test-1
2024-11-09T14:23:18.132-05:00  INFO 14449 --- [myapp] [ionShutdownHook] o.s.b.w.e.tomcat.GracefulShutdown        : Commencing graceful shutdown. Waiting for active requests to complete
2024-11-09T14:23:18.137-05:00  INFO 14449 --- [myapp] [tomcat-shutdown] o.s.b.w.e.tomcat.GracefulShutdown        : Graceful shutdown complete
Shutdown called!


You need to set a timeout period to wait for the current thread to complete.
add below properties:
server.shutdown=graceful
spring.lifecycle.timeout-per-shutdown-phase=20s

Using graceful shutdown with your IDE may not work properly if it does not send a proper SIGTERM signal. See the documentation of your IDE for more details.
For shutdown called u can add actuator :
build.gradle:
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'

add below properties for acutuator:
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health,info,shutdown
management.endpoint.shutdown.enabled=true

you need to set shutdown.enable to get shutdown endpoint from actuator
after calling POST METHOD:  http://{HOST}:{PORT}/{CONTEXT_PATH}/actuator/shutdown
you will get response like below:
    Commencing graceful shutdown. Waiting for active requests to complete
    2024-11-10T11:51:54.904+06:00  INFO 37812 --- [demo] [tomcat-shutdown] o.s.b.w.e.tomcat.GracefulShutdown        : Graceful shutdown complete
    2024-11-10T11:51:54.915+06:00  INFO 37812 --- [demo] [       Thread-1] com.example.demo.MyClass                 : Shutdown called!
    2024-11-10T11:52:01.416+06:00  INFO 37812 --- [demo] [           main] com.example.demo.MyClass                 : Done!
    
Process finished with exit code 0


As explained here, in order to prevent interrupting async running tasks you need to specify the TaskExecutor bean to wait for tasks to complete (with `setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown) method:
@Bean
public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(2);
    taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(2);
    taskExecutor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
    taskExecutor.initialize();
    return taskExecutor;
}


Unfortunately that did not fix the problem. I have edited my question with my changes.
